# check that a result is an ok playframework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to make a slightly better @Cached annotation by making it aware of the parameters of the function I call in my controllers.

so I have this Action :

```
public class ContextualCachedAction extends Action<ContextualCached> {

    @Override
    public Result call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        try {
            String key = makeKey(ctx);
            Integer duration = configuration.duration();
            Result result = (Result) Cache.get(key);
            if (result == null) {
                result = delegate.call(ctx);

                //TODO find a way to cache only successful calls

                Cache.set(key, result, duration);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }

    private String makeKey(Context ctx) {
        //makes the key from some parameters in the ctx.request()
    }
}
```

My question is this : I would like to cache the result of delegate.call() only if it is an Ok(). 
How can I check for that?
Is there a property? 
a util? 
or do I need to Ok().getClass().isInstance(result)?

Thanks for any answers and hints.

PS : Why do I want to do that? Because I have some calls that generate few types of different results. Few enough results that caching them could be an option since I don't want to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `ok` result is actually a `play.mvc.Results.Status` which wraps its Scala counterpart `play.api.mvc.Results.Status`, which in turn has its `status` code set to 200.

So you call `result.getWrappedResult()` and check if the type is right, cast it to `PlainResult` (the lowest common denominator) and call `status`.

This looks very ugly though:

```
  play.api.mvc.Result wrappedResult = result.getWrappedResult();
  if (wrappedResult instanceof play.api.mvc.PlainResult) {
    play.api.mvc.PlainResult plainResult = (play.api.mvc.PlainResult)wrappedResult;
    int code = plainResult.header().status();
    if (code == OK)
      // Cache
  }
```

Comment: Is this the recommended way to do this? This seems really awkward and complicated to achieve something simple like checking the response status code

Comment: What if it is not an instance of `PlainResult`?

Answer (score 8):

Less sucky approach:

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;
import static play.test.Helpers.*;

/* do stuff */

Result result = doSomethingWithController();
assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
```

Works as of 2.2.2.

Comment: This works, but to use that in production code (not in test code), I had to explicity add a dependency to the test libraries, e.g. (for Play with Java 2.2.1): `"com.typesafe.play" % "play-test_2.10" % "2.2.1"`

Comment: Where is `OK` defined?

Answer (score 3):

Just to update this page with the latest 2.3+ Playframework way of doing it.

```
Result result = //.....
int httpStatus = result.toScala().header().status();
```

easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you know your `Result` is an instance of `play.mvc.Results.Status` (which it is if you created it using any of the static helper methods from the `play.mvc.Results` class) you can cast it to `Status`, and get a `SimpleResult` object directly using `getWrappedSimpleResult()`:

```
Status result = (Status) YourController.actionHandler();
int expected = Results.ok()
        .getWrappedSimpleResult().header().status();
int actual = result.getWrappedSimpleResult().header().status();
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```