# How to get the status code out of a Result in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a Java project in the Play framework, version 2.2.1

I'm trying to implement a batch operation on my models, with a message being returned showing the status code of the query on each model instance. So that's one controller method calling another and getting the Result from it.

The thing is, I need to get that status code from that return, since it has to be in the message.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get this status code.

I tried this: [check that a result is an ok playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117643/check-that-a-result-is-an-ok-playframework)

But it won't compile, Java says the cast cannot be done.

So, how do I get that number out of the Result?

Once again, this is a Java project and all my Results are play.mvc.Result, not play.mvc.api.Result.

EDIT:

Let's say you have a route that does a DELETE:

```
DELETE  /url/delete/:id/         myapp.mycontroller.delete(id: Long)
```

The controller method would look like:

```
public static Result delete(Long id) {
    Mymodel m = MyModel.get(id);
    if (m.hasDependencies) {
        throw new CustomException(statusCode, message);
    }
    m.delete();
    return ok();
}
```

So either it passes an ok() or an exception with a custom statuscode.

The batch functionality I am talking about would be another method in the same controller. This would receive a batch of IDs via a form element. The goal would then be to call the required function on all these ids.

The whole point is using the existing controller methods, as they contain other checks and fail-safes that need to be taken in to account for certain models.

So I have another method that receives this list of Ids and then calls the proper function in a loop, in a try/catch block.

The idea is that I want to find out what the statuscode of the Result is. That's it. Nothing more. I want the statuscode of the result.

Comment: Could you post some relevant code illustrating where it fails or where you want to implement this?

Comment: @Ryan: there is no error being thrown. The point of this question is that I cannot find how to get the statuscode out of a result.

Comment: @KdgDev you said there's a compiler error.  What was the compiler error?

Comment: @Ryan I already wrote that in my explanation. 6th line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**play.mvc.Result** is just a wrapper for **play.mvc.api.Result** so after all you will need to work with it.

```
public static Result batch() {
    try {
        Result result = delete(1L);
        play.api.mvc.SimpleResult res = Await.result(result.getWrappedResult(), Duration.Inf());
        int status = res.header().status();
        //handle status
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle exception
    }
}
```

*Await* and *Duration* are Scala classes

```
import scala.concurrent.Await;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I needed to get the body too after this but that didn't work the same way, as Scale will return it as an Enumerator<byte[]>. I didn't find a way to get that parsed so I took a look in the Play Java source code, specifically in the Test Helpers, which contained the functionality I needed.